# PHP MSSQLS Spy on Database Queries

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-injection

So I am working on this project which basically clones the functionalities of a sofware programmed in C# (I have no information about the source code).

**Problem**

I am developing a web application that will do a simple update on the database (db shared with the same software mentioned above). What i want to do? I want to 'spy' the SQL Queries executed by the software and by that, acquiring the information about it to perform my own queries clone a specific feature of that sofware. How can i accomplish that?

**My Solution:**

My idea is, I use the software, specificaly the feature I am interested in, then i check in the database which queries did the software execute and by doing that, i gain information about the updated tables and can code my own features.

*My question is, how can you 'spy' the queries did the software execute using SQL Server Management ?*

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to log all the queries run by the app with [Sql Server Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx).